# Compiler and linker flags in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android.mk

How can I see **generated compiler and linker flags** in the Android Studio for the my project(something like `compiler output` in the another IDEs)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest Android Studio (v2.3 at the time of writing) and pass the "-v" verbose option to C/C++ flags (cFlags/cppFlags).